# I never knew/have never known my grandmother as she died before I was born

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-present-perfect

Turns out the correct way of saying this is:

> I never knew my grandmother as she died before I was born.

Am I right that the reason past simple is used here is because my grandmother is dead and there is no way for me anymore to know her?

And if I said

> I've never known my grandmother.

it would imply the existing opportunity to know her (did I use "know" correctly here or should I have used "get to know"?), i.e. that she is still alive?

Or maybe the better way to explain this is that the time period (before I was born) is already finished? If that is the case, then could I say

> I've never known my grandmother

(without specifying a time frame), even though my grandmother is dead?

Maybe you know where I could find more details about the particular rule that applies here?

Answer (score 1):

The real discord in your second sentence

> I've never known my grandmother […]

is not so much the fact that you no longer have an opportunity to know her, but the fact that you used *never*.

A more concordant phrasing would be

> I never knew my grandmother, since she died before I was born.

Even if your grandmother were still alive (and, for example, you simply never met her), it would be strange to use *have known* with *never*. The reason is that *have known* is typically used to predicate of unbounded (not countable) groups. A context in which we use *have known* with *never* is in phrases like

> I've never known anyone to turn down an offer of ice cream after
>   dinner.